# Incomplete User Accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-models

I'm working on a website where users can make purchases using only their email address, with no account required. If they ever do decide to make an account in the future, all their purchases will get assigned to that account.

So far, I have it so that users `has_many :purchases` and that purchases `belongs_to :user`. The problem is that I don't know how to create a user with only an email address on the first purchase, and then have all later purchases using that email assigned to that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a overall database view, here's what you'll want to go towards:

- Store transactions with an 'email" attribute.
- If a user creates an account, retrieve the sales that have their email address and assign the "user" parameter to the user that has just been created.

This way you are stable and don't have to worry about all of this arm crossing with manipulating user objects.

Comment: This seems like a good solution, but what user would I assign purchases to before they're claimed? I'm pretty sure (although I'm not positive) that you can't just leave models assigned to nothing if they're supposed to belong_to another model.

Comment: You would not assign the purchases to a user if the user did not exist. That is why the user_id field would be left blank.